# How to fix 'jsPDFAPI is not defined'

Tags: jspdf

I'm adding calibri.ttf font into jsPDF file,
According to Use of UTF-8 / TTF: section given in [this github link](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

I followed [this](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html) the page and generated *.js file is included on my project like this.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/calibri-normal.js"></script>
```

and then tried to use font as :

```
var option = {
    orientation: 'l',
    unit: 'in',
    format: [9, 6.9],
    putOnlyUsedFonts: false
}
var lx = 0.5, ly = 1;
var gap = 0.3;
var doc = new jsPDF(option)
//doc.addFont('calibri-normal.ttf', 'calibri', 'normal');
doc.setFontStyle('calibri')
doc.setFontSize(8)
   .text('Custom Font Family Used', lx + 1.0, ly - 0.05);
```

with adding/removing the line here;

```
doc.addFont('calibri-normal.ttf', 'calibri', 'normal');
```

doesn't implement calibri font,
though

```
doc.getFontList()
```

shows the font 'calibri' included, Custom font is not implemented. Still default font is used.

then on inspecting the custom-font.js generated, A error message: 'jsPDFAPI is not defined' is thowing.

[Error Message Thrown in custome-font.js While Inspecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoZcp.png)

How could I fix this 'jsPDFAPI is not defined' issue? 
What I have missed here to implement custom font in jsPDF.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should replace jspdf.min.js by jspdf.debug.js ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had downloaded the library from [here](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) and it was version 1.3.2. After that, i used the cdn version. Currently using 1.5.3 and it works fine. Seems that the files downloaded from the original website were not updated, and most probably the `utf-8` support was not included in 1.3.2 version.

So instead of using that website, just include the latest version from the cdn;
`https://unpkg.com/jspdf@1.5.3/dist/jspdf.min.js`